# Calculate a failure rate based on row values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame where a row is the instance of an item that passes or fails (Result column). The instance is associated with a Device (A, B, or C) and also a Batch (1-50). I'd like to be able to calculate the rate of failure (fails/total) in each Batch per Device.

| Device | Batch | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Fail |
| A | 1 | Pass |
| A | 2 | Fail |
| A | 2 | Fail |
| A | 2 | Pass |
| A | 2 | Fail |
| B | 1 | Pass |
| B | 1 | Pass |

So for device A, batch 1, I need the failure rate calculation to be 0.50 or 50%, for device A batch 2, it would be 0.75 or 75%, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
out = df.groupby(["Device", "Batch"]).agg(lambda x: x.eq("Fail").sum() / len(x))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
              Result
Device Batch        
1      1        0.50
       2        0.75
2      1        0.50
```

Comment: This seemed to work. Can I drop other columns from the print out that are irrelevant?

Comment: @cjm154 Do you want to reset index? then `out = out.reset_index(drop=True)` <- that will keep only the `Result` column. Or `out = out.reset_index()` and select only columns you want.